# How to trigger multi job phase in Jenkins using the Boolean parameters as trigger condition?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need right direction to set-up my Multijob project to work as per my requirements. My scenario:

1. I have a Multijob pipeline with multiple Global Boolean parameters(A, B, C, a, b, c) that will be passed as environment variables to my Downstream jobs.
2. I am using Multiple conditional steps with Boolean condition ${ENV,var="A"} to trigger my multijob phase 1, ${ENV,var="B"} to trigger multijob phase 2 etc.
3. My Multijob phase 1 has 4 phase jobs(Job A, Job B, Job C, Job D) that needs to be triggered based on the Global  Boolean parameters chosen. If a is chosen then trigger Job A, if b is chosen Job B etc.

I was able to set-up step 2 and step 3. But my phase jobs Job A, Job B should copy artifacts based on the global Boolean parameters A or B dynamically. (if A is chosen then Job A will copy artifacts of A)  how can I achieve this? Is this even possible with Boolean parameters?

Comment: perhaps add some code of where your at so far. this is hard to digest without seeing what you have to start off with

Comment: it is a freestyle Jenkins project, I can add screenshots though..